# How to filter duplicated elements until a new one comes

Tags: arrays, swift, filter, duplicates

I want to filter out the duplicated elements until a new element comes using Swift. and I want to do this for the whole array.

Example: [1,1,1,2,2,1]

Output: [1,2,1]

Comment: Please show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck

Comment: Actually, I have a realm database which I get the array out of it, and in this array, I have duplicated elements, which I want to filter to have the unique ones in a sequence.
if I share my code here it would be more confusing, the thing that I want to have in my output is what I have described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce(into:_:)` to do so:

```
let array = [1,1,1,2,2,1]
let filtered = array.reduce(into: [Int]()) { partialResult, current in
    guard let last = partialResult.last else { partialResult.append(current); return }
    if last != current {
        partialResult.append(current)
    }
}
print(filtered)
```

We iterate over the array.
`partialResult` is the current new array being populated.
We check if there is already an initial value, else we add it.
Then, we compare last value of the `partialResult` with current value iterated of the initial array to decide if we append it or not to `partialResult`

Once you understood the logic, it could also be written with:

```
let filtered2 = array.reduce(into: [Int]()) { partialResult, current in
    if partialResult.last != current {
        partialResult.append(current)
    }
}
print(filtered2)
```

Comment: thx a lot for your useful answer, could you please help me with this issue as well, I'm using realm database and when i want to append to partialResult, I get this error "No exact matches in call to instance method 'append'"
`let data = RealmManager().fetchLocations(by: uuid)
        
        let filtered2 = data.reduce(into: [ActivityModel]()) { partialResult, current in
            if partialResult.last?.motionType != current.motionType {
                partialResult.append(current)
            }
        }`

Comment: That's strange. I tried to reproduce, but couldn't have the error. Are you sure `data` is a `[ActivityModel]`? If it's a [[ActivityModel]], there is that error, but also another one for the `if` line.